# Arranging multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

I'm trying to use array_push, but the results isn't what I need. I need a different result set, but I'm not sure how to do with just array_push. Or is there a different way to do this?

```
$array[0][0] = 0;
$array[0][1] = 0;
$array[0][2] = 0;
$array[1][0] = 1;
$array[1][1] = 1;
$array[1][2] = 1;
$array[2][0] = 2;
$array[2][1] = 2;
$array[2][2] = 2;

$count = count($array);
$tempArray = array();
while ($count > 0) {
$count--;

if ($array[$count][2] > 0) {
array_push($tempArray, $array[$count][0], $array[$count][1]);
} //end of if ($array[$count][2] > 0)

} //end of while ($count > 0)

print_r($tempArray);
```

**Result:**

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 2 )
```

**Need Result:**

```
Array ( [0][0] => 1 [0][1] => 1 [1][0] => 2 [1][1] => 2 )
```

Comment: your not doing yourself any favors with an example like that

Comment: @Dagon What's wrong with it? Anyway, I think I'll just array_push $array[$count], and have the extra one dangling, since I don't need it, but it's fine for it to be there, since I'm extracting 0, and 1 anyways.

Comment: I agree. Beside, using while is not gonna help at all. Better use a foreach to get a key to array_push like $temparray[$key]

Comment: Just two little modifications you need to make: 1)  Don't push them as single values: `$array[$count][0], $array[$count][1]` but as an array, so you get your two dimensional structure: `[$array[$count][0], $array[$count][1]]` 2) Don't count from top to bottom, but from bottom to top

Comment: must just be me but my brain does not cope well with multiple variables all either 1 or 0